# How to base CSS on parallel DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a procedurally generated visualisation that switches between mine and my friends visualizations, removing them from the DOM in the process and reintroducing them when need be (This needs to be the case).

On the footer, there is a bit of text that is only relevant to one view.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div id='myvis'>The Vis</div>
</div>
<footer><p>Hi Mom</p></footer>
```

But then #myvis will be removed from the DOM and replaced with this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div id='myfriendsvis'>The Vis</div>
</div>
<footer><p>Hi Mom</p></footer>
```

But I obviously don't want to say Hi mom here, because why would my mom be viewing my friends vis?

Since they are parallel, I can't necessary say

```
#myfriendsvis p {
display: none;
}
```

I also tried

```
#myfriendsvis ~ p {
display: none;
}
```

I also wrote this:

```
    function myFunction(x) {
    if (slides) {
        HiMom.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        HiMom.style.display = "block";
    }
};

const slides = document.getElementById('myfriendsvis').style.width == 1024; // basically saying if this item exists in the dom, it'll exist with this style, so if its there do this
const HiMom = document.getElementsByClassName('footer p'); // IK its not a class but you get it
myFunction(slides) // Call listener function at run time
slides.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

But because myfriendsvis comes 2nd, it doesn't exist in the DOM.

Is there a way I can css the p based on another element above despite the fact it's nested?

Accepting JS, CSS, and HTML advice. Might be tricky to implement but I'll solve it.

Comment: As amusing as the humor is, I removed it, assuming this post to be genuine.  Don't want folks to think this is a troll post.

Comment: I'm glad you enjoyed it, even for a moment. I will remember this for the future. Thank you Robert.

Comment: did you try giving the div with myvis/myfriendsvis a class and than select it in javascript, and onchange you check for the id, then if the id is equal to myfriendsvis run some code

Comment: not posting this as answer since im not sure it works, and dont know what way the id gets toggled

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a pure css solution is not possible, because you would have to get the parent of `#myfriendsvis` and that is currently not possible.

In order to get it to work, I updated your Javascript:

```
    function myFunction(x) {

    if (slides) {
        HiMom.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        HiMom.style.display = "block";
    }
};

const slides = document.getElementById('myfriendsvis')
slides.style.width == 1024; // basically saying if this item exists in the dom, it'll exist with this style, so if its there do this
const HiMom = document.querySelector('footer p'); // IK its not a class but you get it

myFunction(slides) // Call listener function at run time
slides.addEventListener("onload",myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Doing the `slides` style update in one go, caused it's value to become false instead of a node. So I made it a two step process. I also use a querySelector, as it will only return one node instead of a collection and I used an `onload` event listener. Depending on your use case, you may have to update it with an update event listener.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/bGVXbVX) for you to play around with.

Comment: Thanks so much for having an attempt. One of the key issues with this function is that because the visualizations from one another switch out, there is no 'slides' when the vis first runs. It's not in the DOM, so it cannot read slides.style.width.

Comment: Is there any way you can add a class or data-element to the parent of ```#myfriendsvis```? Another option is to add the event listener to the body or to some other element which is always there.